# try to display htmltag string in extjs pie chart legend text

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, legend, pie-chart

before

[image]

after

[image]

my code link (for refrence):
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/d32

Comment: <test> and <metric three> are not html tags? (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp) What you want to display in Legend should be with purpose. Can you detail that.

Comment: Which version of Ext js you have?

Comment: You want to display < and > in the legend?

Comment: use extjs 5.0 @Gilsha

Comment: need to display as it is like : <test> @Jayaprasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do html encoding of data before binding it to the store.  Try this.

```
var holdData = [{
    'name': '<test>',
    'data': 10
 }, {
    'name': 'metric two',
    'data': 7
 }, {
   'name': '<metric three>',
   'data': 5
 }, {
   'name': 'metric four',
   'data': 2
 }, {
   'name': 'metric five',
   'data': 27
}];

holdData.map(function(d){ d.name=Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(d.name); return d; });

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
   fields: ['name', 'data'],
   data: holdData
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt; and &gt;` to display < and > symbols respectively in the html page.

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: ['name', 'data'],
        data: [{
            'name': '&lt;test&gt;',
            'data': 10
        }, {
            'name': 'metric two',
            'data': 7
        }, {
            'name': '&lt;metric three&gt;',
            'data': 5
        }, {
            'name': 'metric four',
            'data': 2
        }, {
            'name': 'metric five',
            'data': 27
        }]
    });
```

[image]

This is simple HTML fix. ExtJS does not have anything to do with this. What ExtJS does in displaying the lengend is, ExtJS takes the value in the 'name' attribute of the store-->data part and embeds it to the HTML span tag as,

```
['<div class="', Ext.baseCSSPrefix, 'legend-container">', '<tpl for=".">', '<div class="', Ext.baseCSSPrefix, 'legend-item">', '<span ', 'class="', Ext.baseCSSPrefix, 'legend-item-marker {[ values.disabled ? Ext.baseCSSPrefix + \'legend-inactive\' : \'\' ]}" ', 'style="background:{mark};">', '</span>{name}', '</div>', '</tpl>', '</div>']
```

[see here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.Legend)

You might also want to take a look over [entity characters in html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)